# Should I use constraints or size properties for ConstraintLayout elements?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

When using Android `ConstraintLayout`, should I favour constraints over size properties (`layout_width`, `layout_height`) or the other way around? I'm asking mostly from a performance point of view but any comments are appreciated.

As an example, let's say I have

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

Then I could get rid of both `layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf` and `layout_constraintRight_toRightOf`, or leave them and change `layout_width` to 0dp and have the same result.

Of course I would remove any unused constraint or property to make code cleaner and easier to understand, but does it have any other drawbacks I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [**`ConstraintLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) & [**`Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).

[**`MATCH_PARENT`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT) is not recommended for widgets contained in a
 ***ConstraintLayout***. Similar behavior can be defined by using
 **MATCH_CONSTRAINT** with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom
 constraints being set to `"parent"`.

- Using **`0dp`**, which is the equivalent of **MATCH_CONSTRAINT** (The view expands as much as possible to meet the constraints on each side)

You can also use ratio if both dimensions are set to **`MATCH_CONSTRAINT (0dp)`**. In this case the system sets the largest dimensions that satisfies all constraints and maintains the aspect ratio specified.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that paragraph for some reason. Any ideas about *why* is it not recommended? As it says, you can achieve similar behavior both ways